# Accumulation point and analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $E$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ (the set of complex numbers). Let $K \subset E$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a analytic function. Then prove that

$$\mbox{acc}(f(K)) \subset f(\mbox{acc}(K)),$$

where $\mbox{acc}(K)$ denotes the set of accumulation points of $K$.

Comment: You should say what you tried to do in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true for any continuous function on a compact set. If $\zeta$ is in LHS then there exists $(z_n)$ such that $f(z_n)$ are distinct and converge to $\zeta$. It follows that $z_n$ 's are distinct and there is a subsequence $z_{n_j}$ converging to some point $z \in K$. it follows that $z$ is an accumulation point of $K$ and $\zeta =f(z)$.